# Would I say, "All he needs is his blanket, hammock, and pillow." or "All he needs are his blanket, hammock, and pillow."?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

The difference is after the word 'needs'. is it 'is'? or is it 'are'? Thanks to anyone who can answer this.

Comment: Since it's multiple items, you use the plural.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you interpret *his blanket, hammock, and pillow*.

Do you think of the phrase as three separate items, or do you think of it as a compound item?

Multiple separate items use *are*. If the phrase is interpreted that way, then look at a reconstructed version of the sentence:

> His blanket, his hammock, and his pillow **are** all he needs.

But just because there are several things, that doesn't mean they can't be a compound:

- Milk and cookies **is** my favourite snack.
- Life, liberty, and happiness **is** what I want.

> His blanket, hammock, and pillow **is** all he needs.

---

Compound items are often those that are commonly paired together and said often. Based on that, *his blanket, hammock and pillow* would very probably be interpreted as completely separate items, because they are not a common pairing. As such, it would be more common to use *are*.

However, there's no *essential* reason that those three things could not be interpreted as a compound item if you wanted to see them in that way.